# Split very long javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, reactjs

I have this long string coming from a database and I have to break it apart and be able to throw it into a json format. That part I know I won't have issues with but i'm strugglign with how to break it apart.

```
LAST ADMISSION DATE,LAST ASSESSMENT DATE,LAST DISCHARGE DATE,LAST MH 
SAFETY PLAN,NEXT MH APPT DATE,ON TRACK,PATIENT NAME,PATIENT PRF,PRF                 
REVIEW,^widgetcolumns\nHIGH RISK^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH 
CENTER,^widgetloc,42^instrID,PHQ9^instrName,S^instrScore|\nSUD^widget     
inactive,3180601\nTRIAGE^widgetTRIAGE 
WIDGET^widgettitle5^widgettype\nTRIAGE^widget,LAST APPOINTMENT,PATIENT  
NAME,^widgetcolumns\nTRIAGE^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH CENTER,26|MENTAL 
HYGIENE-OPC,^widgetloc,\nHIGH RISK^widget,APPOINTMENT DATE,LAST 
ASSESSMENT DATE,MH LAST APPT 
DATE,^criteriafields,RG,GE,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2016- 
12/31/2018,01/01/2016,01/01/2010,^criteriaval\nTRIAGE^widget,APPOINTMENT 
DATE,^criteriafields,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2015,^criteriaval\nERROR: 
TRIAGE^wdgt,,^BAD APPT DATES\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,
09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,2^count,379^dfn,SEVENTYNINE,PATIENT^patname,
07/01/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,3^count,766^dfn,SEVENTYONE,PATIENT^patname,
06/12/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,4^count,100848^dfn,AVIVAPATIENT,EIGHT^patname,
01/24/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n
```

I apologize in advance for this super long string but I need pretty much

```
"HIGH RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,"
```

from that string to the bottom. So everything above what I had in quotes is throw away.

Is there a way to do this without butting my head against the wall? The thing is nothing can be hard coded because all the data is different based on whoever is logged in.

> **UPDATE:** For those who are asking about the desired output. I want this as one big string without everything else.

```
"HIGH RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,
09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n
HIGH RISK^widget,2^count,379^dfn,SEVENTYNINE,PATIENT^patname,
07/01/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n
HIGH RISK^widget,3^count,766^dfn,SEVENTYONE,PATIENT^patname,
06/12/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n
HIGH RISK^widget,4^count,100848^dfn,AVIVAPATIENT,EIGHT^patname,
01/24/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n"
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Star by splitting at the line breaks and see what each line looks like then parse those lines

Comment: That's what I did, which is cool because that works but how would I take out the arrays with only the information that I need? That's really the part that i'm struggling with.

Comment: Use Array#filter and search for what you want on each line. Return true if the match exists and false if not

Comment: `The thing is nothing can be hard coded because all the data is different based on whoever is logged in.` Well, you don't even give general (common) keywords which need to be _hardcoded_.

Comment: Please post the desired output.

Comment: @KoshVery I put an update section in the initial post for what I wanted in the output.

Comment: Does the needed string always starts with `HIGH RISK^widget,1` ?

Comment: ummm that's honestly a great question. I think I may be safe with that. What would be the regex code to go up until that? @Ibrahim i've never worked with regex before. I have to give credit where credit is due. This code is from jmcgriz.

      str = str.replace(/\n|\\n/g, ' ')
    .replace(/^.+?high/i, 'HIGH')

Would that be the code but replace the high with "HIGH RISK^widget,1"?

Comment: You can do something like this `[\s\S]*?(?=HIGH\s*?RISK\^widget,1\^)`. Example: https://regex101.com/r/HNvvpc/1/

Comment: @Ibrahim Ok cool, thank you that works perfectly. Now inside of javascript i can do something like .replace(/\n|\\n/g, " ").replace(/[\s\S]*?(?=HIGH\s*?RISK\^widget,1\^))       ?

Comment: Something like this: `YouString.replace(/[\s\S]*?(?=HIGH\s*?RISK\^widget,1\^)/, '');`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a little bit of a rookie with stackoverflow. Is there a way to make your comment the correct answer?

Comment: Glad I can help. I posted my answer for future readers!

Comment: As for your question, no, you cannot accept comments as accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
[\s\S]*?(?=HIGH\s*?RISK\^widget,1\^)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/HNvvpc/1/

Complete JS:

```js
var String = "LAST ADMISSION DATE,LAST ASSESSMENT DATE,LAST DISCHARGE DATE,LAST MH SAFETY PLAN,NEXT MH APPT DATE,ON TRACK,PATIENT NAME,PATIENT PRF,PRF REVIEW,^widgetcolumns\nHIGH RISK^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH CENTER,^widgetloc,42^instrID,PHQ9^instrName,S^instrScore|\nSUD^widget inactive,3180601\nTRIAGE^widgetTRIAGE WIDGET^widgettitle5^widgettype\nTRIAGE^widget,LAST APPOINTMENT,PATIENT NAME,^widgetcolumns\nTRIAGE^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH CENTER,26|MENTAL HYGIENE-OPC,^widgetloc,\nHIGH RISK^widget,APPOINTMENT DATE,LAST ASSESSMENT DATE,MH LAST APPT DATE,^criteriafields,RG,GE,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2016- 12/31/2018,01/01/2016,01/01/2010,^criteriaval\nTRIAGE^widget,APPOINTMENT DATE,^criteriafields,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2015,^criteriaval\nERROR: TRIAGE^wdgt,,^BAD APPT DATES\nHIGH RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH RISK^widget,2^count,379^dfn,SEVENTYNINE,PATIENT^patname,07/01/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH RISK^widget,3^count,766^dfn,SEVENTYONE,PATIENT^patname,06/12/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH RISK^widget,4^count,100848^dfn,AVIVAPATIENT,EIGHT^patname,01/24/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n"
console.log(String.replace(/[\s\S]*?(?=HIGH\s*?RISK\^widget,1\^)/, ''));
```

To delete `^` and everything that follows inside an array, use this simple regex `\^.*` with a loop. Example:

```js
var Arr = ["HIGH RISK^widget", "1^count", "3^dfn", "EIGHT", "PATIENT^patname", "09/04/2018^reviewdate", "ACTIVE^status", "HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag"];

for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) { 
    console.log(Arr[i].replace(/\^.*/, ''));   
}
```

Comment: Hey Ibrahim i'm sorry to bother you, I just have one more question.

["HIGH RISK^widget", "1^count", "3^dfn", "EIGHT", "PATIENT^patname", "09/04/2018^reviewdate", "ACTIVE^status", "HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag"]

if I have that array of strings. Is there a way to delete the ^ and everything that follows until the end of each string?

Comment: @JeffreyYourman, you could use this simple regex `\^.*` with a loop. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out all newlines and newline symbols first, then replace everything from the beginning of the string to the first instance of HIGH with "HIGH"

```js
var str = `LAST ADMISSION DATE,LAST ASSESSMENT DATE,LAST DISCHARGE DATE,LAST MH 
SAFETY PLAN,NEXT MH APPT DATE,ON TRACK,PATIENT NAME,PATIENT PRF,PRF                 
REVIEW,^widgetcolumns\nHIGH RISK^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH 
CENTER,^widgetloc,42^instrID,PHQ9^instrName,S^instrScore|\nSUD^widget     
inactive,3180601\nTRIAGE^widgetTRIAGE 
WIDGET^widgettitle5^widgettype\nTRIAGE^widget,LAST APPOINTMENT,PATIENT  
NAME,^widgetcolumns\nTRIAGE^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH CENTER,26|MENTAL 
HYGIENE-OPC,^widgetloc,\nHIGH RISK^widget,APPOINTMENT DATE,LAST 
ASSESSMENT DATE,MH LAST APPT 
DATE,^criteriafields,RG,GE,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2016- 
12/31/2018,01/01/2016,01/01/2010,^criteriaval\nTRIAGE^widget,APPOINTMENT 
DATE,^criteriafields,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2015,^criteriaval\nERROR: 
TRIAGE^wdgt,,^BAD APPT DATES\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,
09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,2^count,379^dfn,SEVENTYNINE,PATIENT^patname,
07/01/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,3^count,766^dfn,SEVENTYONE,PATIENT^patname,
06/12/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH 
RISK^widget,4^count,100848^dfn,AVIVAPATIENT,EIGHT^patname,
01/24/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n`


function output(){
  str = str.replace(/\n|\\n/g, ' ')
    .replace(/^.+?high/i, 'HIGH')
  
  return str
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = output()
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `split`, `slice` and `join`:

```js
var str = "LAST ADMISSION DATE,LAST ASSESSMENT DATE,LAST DISCHARGE DATE,LAST MH SAFETY PLAN,NEXT MH APPT DATE,ON TRACK,PATIENT NAME,PATIENT PRF,PRF REVIEW,^widgetcolumns\nHIGH RISK^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH CENTER,^widgetloc,42^instrID,PHQ9^instrName,S^instrScore|\nSUD^widget inactive,3180601\nTRIAGE^widgetTRIAGE WIDGET^widgettitle5^widgettype\nTRIAGE^widget,LAST APPOINTMENT,PATIENT NAME,^widgetcolumns\nTRIAGE^widget,17|MENTAL HEALTH CENTER,26|MENTAL HYGIENE-OPC,^widgetloc,\nHIGH RISK^widget,APPOINTMENT DATE,LAST ASSESSMENT DATE,MH LAST APPT DATE,^criteriafields,RG,GE,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2016- 12/31/2018,01/01/2016,01/01/2010,^criteriaval\nTRIAGE^widget,APPOINTMENT DATE,^criteriafields,GE,^criteriaexp,01/01/2015,^criteriaval\nERROR: TRIAGE^wdgt,,^BAD APPT DATES\nHIGH RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH RISK^widget,2^count,379^dfn,SEVENTYNINE,PATIENT^patname,07/01/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH RISK^widget,3^count,766^dfn,SEVENTYONE,PATIENT^patname,06/12/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\nHIGH RISK^widget,4^count,100848^dfn,AVIVAPATIENT,EIGHT^patname,01/24/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag\n"

console.log(str.split('\n').slice(1).join('\\n'))
```

If you need your srting joined with linebreaks use `.join('\n')`.