# remove parts of a javascript string from ^ to " or ^ to a comma

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this string and or array coming from a database and I have to break it apart from either the ^ up until the comma or from the array it would be the ^ until the end of the string. It will include the ^ but will not include the comma or ", I know I posted the other day about a similar issue. I would like to use regex but any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
"HIGH RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT,PATIENT^patname,
09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag"

["HIGH RISK^widget", "1^count", "3^dfn", "EIGHT", "PATIENT^patname", 
"09/04/2018^reviewdate", "ACTIVE^status", "HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag"]
```

UPDATE: The answer is (\^)[\s\S]*?(?="). I'm sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: can you share your attempts (code)

Comment: Hey! that's you again with your [long-long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505040/split-very-long-javascript-string/51508479#51508479) problem?

Comment: Yes Kosh, that was me. To be completely honest, I've spent  2 days trying to figure out regex and I just don't understand it at the moment. I only have 2 days to figure out this splitting issue and I just don't have time.

Comment: You say you want to remove parts of the string starting from `^` and ending at a `"` or a comma, but nothing in the resulting array has any substring removed after any of the `^`s?

Comment: Hey CertainPerformance. So we'll stick to one of the options. Inside the array. I would like to remove for example ^widget and stop right before the ". so the regex would be something like include ^ and remove everything until the ". I'm going to run a loop to hit the rest of them.

Comment: I figured it out. I guess I just needed to calm down a bit and relax lol.

(\^)[\s\S]*?(?=")

that is the regex code i'm using to start and look for the ^ and then go up until the "

I'm sorry to bother everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will suit your needs although the question isn't completely clear i think this is what you are looking for.

```js
var test = "HIGH RISK^widget,1^count,3^dfn,EIGHT''test,PATIENT^patname,09/04/2018^reviewdate,ACTIVE^status,HIGH RISK FOR SUICIDE^flag";

var pairs = test.split(',');
console.log(pairs);

var mapped = pairs.map(pair => pair.substring(0, pair.search(/\^|\'\'/) + 1));
console.log(mapped);
```